# convert from spherical co-ordinate system to cartesian

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to convert  $ρ=\cos{ϕ}$ to Cartesian system , after conversion my answer is $z=x^2+y^2+z^2$ , but its not a sphere , what have I done wrong?

Comment: There is more than one convention for spherical coordinates: What are your formulas for converting from Cartesian to spherical coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a sphere:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2-z=0\implies\\
x^2+y^2+z^2-z+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{4}\implies\\
x^2+y^2+(z-\frac{1}{2})^2=\frac{1}{4}$$

However when you ask, you should state your angle $\phi$ represents the polar angle, and why you expect it as a sphere.